# OpenVPN is not working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: openvpn

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 in my Sony Vaio E-Series laptop but OpenVPN is not working in lastest version of Ubuntu.

I used OpenVPN in 13.10 and it worked perfectly but in 14.04 its not working.

Comment: are you having issues with openvpn itself or network-manager-openvpn? That is can you setup a vpn via the command line? Do check the bug reports on launchpad.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems in Ubuntu 14.04 related to OpenVPN, a bug has been opened in Launchpad: [#1294899 Import saved VPN connection has been Recently Broken](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-openvpn/+bug/1294899)

The problem has still not been repaired, so you need to install a package named `network-manager-openvpn` (which you can do in the Ubuntu Software Center).